# CGContext does not retain rendered lines

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgcontext

I have a drawRect implementation:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (self.colorToRender)
    {
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, self.colorToRender.CGColor);
    }
    else
    {
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx,[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    }

    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, self.center.x, self.center.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, self.pointToRender.x, self.pointToRender.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

This renders a line each time, but the rendered lines are never left on screen.

How would I render a new line to screen keeping the previously rendered lines?

Comment: Most likely your view's clearsContextBeforeDrawing flag is set (this is the default, and it is also ticked in XIB by default) -> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clearsContextBeforeDrawing

Answer (score 0):

drawRect gets called each time the view needs drawing. If you want to draw multiple lines, you have to draw each line again in the drawRect method.

When adding a line, add the line to an array that you can use in the drawRect method to determine what lines to draw.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (self.colorToRender)
    {
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, self.colorToRender.CGColor);
    }
    else
    {
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx,[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    }


    // For each line you want to draw:
    for (MyLine *thisLine in myLines) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, thisLine.startPoint.x, thisLine.startPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, thisLine.endPoint.x, thisLine.endPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am calling setNeedsDisplay for each line and I have now set the clearContextBeforeDrawing to NO in the views initWithFrame method. I get the same results. I ended up using a BiezerPath and it seems to work better.

Comment: @Helium3 Are you sure that one is getting called, and not `initWithCoder:` (i.e. from XIB)?